# Как создать объект содержащий объекты с уникальными именами?

Tags: javascript

В чём смысл: есть массив множества объектов, их может быть тысяча. У них есть определенные пары ключ-значение. Мне нужно заполнить один другой объект новыми объектами так, чтобы именем объекта стало одно из значений в переборе из массива. При этом, нужно чтобы получился уникальный список, при этом же, чтобы была проверка на существование, дабы не перезаписывать тысячу раз одно и то же.

Изначально я сделал это с массивом с именованными ключами, но по определенным причинам это мне не подходит:

```
array.forEach(item => {
   if (item.type in object === false) {
       object[item.type] = {
           somekey: item.somekey,
           ...
       }
   }
}
```

Если же делать иначе, то получается, что ключ записывается всегда один:

```
array.forEach(item => {
   if (item.type in object === false) {
       object = {
           [item.type]: {
               somekey: item.somekey,
               ...
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Можно сделать через `Object.assign(array, { [item.type]: { ... })`, но, как говорил, мне не нужно перезаписывать объект, так как далее у меня идёт итерация одного параметра по свойству, то есть `object.item_type_name.somekey += 1;`. А с данным способом значение всегда будет 1. А, ну и как выяснилось, это аналогично первому методу. А мне это не подходит, т.к. во vue эти данные перестают быть реактивными.

UPD:
Кажется придумал как описать проблему проще.
Если вложенный объект создан вручную, то всё ок:
`object: { object_name: { props } }`
Если вложенный объект создан через квадратные скобки, как через ключ массива, то не ок:
`object[object_name] = { props }`

где object_name в квадратных скобках это у нас строковое значение из свойства другого объекта в цикле

На скрине видно, как выглядит объект в secondary(правильно) и как в main (неправильно)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пример результата приведите. И про реактивность не понял.

Comment: Пример привести сложно, ведь в консоли всё выглядит +- одинаково. Только правильный вариант выглядит как object_name: Object который можно раскрыть.
А неправильный выглядит как object_name: {props} сразу раскрытый.
Но в сущности, ходить по свойствам можно одинаково. Однако, для vue есть большая разница. Так, если изменить у "неправильного" объекта какое-то свойство, то перерендер не произойдёт, vue этого не увидит.
Кажется придумал как описать проблему проще, дополню в текст вопроса

Comment: @doox911  добавил скрин

Comment: вы приведите пример конкретных входных данных и желаемого результата.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, перед своим циклом я создаю пустой объект
`var firstObj = {}`
Далее в цикле через `Object.assign(firstObj, {[item.type: { props } })` создаю новый, и добавляю его в главный объект так же через Object.assign:
`object = Object.assign({}, firstObj)`

Comment: Кажется, и вопрос, и ответ - поняли только Вы))

Comment: так бывает, когда он нетривиальный